# BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) when running Berry

Tags: linux, c, window-manager, elementary-os

When I run the [berry](https://berrywm.org/) window manager from the CLI I receive the following error.

```
X Error of failed request: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
Serial number of failed request: 32
Current serial number in output stream: 38
```

I attempted to copy the `.xininitrc` which seemed to fix it for this guy https://github.com/JLErvin/berry/issues/74

However it did not fix the error so I just removed the `.xinitrc` file again.

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?